# Finding the maximum positive number supported by python

Tags: python

I am asked to find the maximum positive number that can be supported by python. I wrote a code and got the correct answer, but then I messed a number up in the code and now I can't find what I did wrong. Can someone help me out? thanks :)

```html
max = 1
max_precision= 1

float('inf')

while max != float('inf'):
    max = max * 10
    max_precision = max_precision + 1
print (precision)
```

The answer should give out 309 which is the right answer(and I got it once) but now the code keeps running endlessly and isn't giving me an answer

Comment: How did you decide that "maximum positive number supported by python" is 309?

Answer (score 3):

Here you're looking for the max value an `int` can store. In Python3 the `int` type is unbounded. This means there is no real limit to the values it can store. See this excerpt from the docs:

> PEP 237: Essentially, long renamed to int. That is, there is only one
> built-in integral type, named int; but it behaves mostly like the old
> long type.
>
> PEP 238: An expression like 1/2 returns a float. Use 1//2
> to get the truncating behavior. (The latter syntax has existed for
> years, at least since Python 2.2.)
>
> The sys.maxint constant was
> removed, since there is no longer a limit to the value of integers.
> However, sys.maxsize can be used as an integer larger than any
> practical list or string index. It conforms to the implementation’s
> “natural” integer size and is typically the same as sys.maxint in
> previous releases on the same platform (assuming the same build
> options).

Documentation link: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Answer (score 0):

`max` is initialized to `1` which is an instance of `int`:

```
>>> type(max)
<class 'int'>
```

When you multiply it by `10`, another `int`, the result is an `int`, not a `float`.

Try initializing `max = 1.0` instead. Including a decimal point creates a `float`. Multiplying a `float` by an `int` results in another `float` so the rest of the code works as-is.

Your final value of `max_precision` will be one greater than the true value because you add one even after your value goes out of range.

(It would be best to use a variable name other than `max` because `max()` is a built-in function.)

What you are really finding is the maximum *n* such that the value 10^*n* can be represented by a Python `float`. This is not really the "maximum positive number that can be supported by python".

You could also look at:

```
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

And if you wanted the number of digits in base 10,

```
>>> math.floor(math.log(sys.float_info.max)/math.log(10))+1
309
```

Answer (score 0):

the maximum number? float do have a maximum, you can find it in the sys module, and they are system dependent if your machine is 32 or 64 bit

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.max
1.7976931348623157e+308
>>>
```

int? they don't have any fix maximum, so the question here is how much ram you have... with enough of it you can calculate this for example `2**(10**100)`